# What is the best practice regarding setting Id's of contained entities in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Assuming i have the following entities that i store in a database using entity framework core

```
public class Container{
  public int ContainerId {get; set;}
  public int ContainedId {get; set;}
  public Contained Contained {get; set;}
}

public class Contained {
  public int ContainedId {get; set;}
  public int ValueA {get; set;}
  public int ValueB {get; set;}
}
```

if at some point in time i decide to save a Container class, with a know Contained class should i manually set the Id?

```
var containerToSave = new Container{
  Contained = contained;
  ContainedId = contained.ContainedId
}
```

or this is a bad practice? If I set it with an id that doesnt match the one in the actual class what will it save?

Answer (score 0):

As far as Entity Framework goes you can specify either a foreign key or add the related entity when saving the main one.

To answer your question... No, is not a bad practice and this isn't related to the EF either. Rather your `Container` matches the `Contained` is a business related problem and should be treated and validated there. EF role in your case is to save the data whatever method you choose.

Assuming you mark the `Contained` EF will give you 2 choices:

```
public virtual Contained Contained { get; set; }
```

1. Add the foreign key:

   ```
   var containerToSave = new Container 
   {
       ContainedId = contained.ContainedId
   }
   ```
2. Add the entity itself:

   ```
   var containerToSave = new Container 
   {
       Contained = new Contained
       {
           ValueA = x;
           ValueB = y;
       }
   }
   ```

In you case, if you already have the `Contained` added, you can go with the first one but not the less, either of above methods are working just fine.

Comment: I think the question is about `ContainedId` and `Contained` properties (i.e. entity having both explicit FK and reference navigation properties). What happens if you set both and they don't match - which one will be in effect?